# Evaluate a definite integral of a periodic function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Suppose $\rho:R\rightarrow R^+$ is a $C^2$ periodic function with period $2\pi$, could you prove
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(\rho'(\theta))^2-\rho(\theta)\rho''(\theta)}{\rho^2(\theta)+(\rho'(\theta))^2}d\theta=0?$$

Comment: What is the motivation for this integral? Do you know of a function in that space for which this is true?

Comment: Use this formula, we can conclude the total curvature of a planar curve is exact $2\pi$.@Αδριανός

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Note that
$$
\left(\frac{\rho(\theta)}{\rho'(\theta)}\right)'=\frac{(\rho'(\theta))^2-\rho(\theta)\rho''(\theta)}{(\rho'(\theta))^2}
$$
So if $\rho'(\theta)\ne 0$, we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(\rho'(\theta))^2-\rho(\theta)\rho''(\theta)}{\rho^2(\theta)+(\rho'(\theta))^2}d\theta&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(\rho'(\theta))^2}{\rho^2(\theta)+(\rho'(\theta))^2}d\left(\frac{\rho(\theta)}{\rho'(\theta)}\right)
\\
&=\arctan{\left(\frac{\rho(\theta)}{\rho'(\theta)}\right)}\Bigg|_0^{2\pi}
\\
&=0
\end{align}
Note that $\rho'(\theta)$ is also a periodic function with period $2\pi$.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!@hermes